# How do you read a 32-bit TIFF image in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, matplotlib, tiff, 32-bit

I want to read 32-bit float image files with python to do some image analysis.

I have tried

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = plt.imread('path_to_file.tif')
```

But, this only reads the data as 8-bit integer values. Is there a way to provide imread() with the right data type?

-- Well, it formerly worked out of the box with 16-bit TIFF files, but doesn't with 32-bit floats.

Answer (score 11):

I experienced a similar problem trying to read single-channel 32-bit integer images. The solution I came up with was:

```
from skimage import io
im = io.imread('path_to_file.tif')
```

If you have OpenCV installed on your computer you could also try:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('path_to_file.tif', -1)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It worked fine using skimage but I get a NoneType when using opencv (using python3.6)

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: I'm using opencv 3.4.2 with python 3.6 from Anaconda 3 (5.2.0)

Comment: Could you share your image through Dropbox, Google drive, etc... ?

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me (the key flag being `IMREAD_ANYDEPTH`):

```py
cv2.imread(fullImagePath, flags=(cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH))
```

I found it here:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/7025

Answer (score 3):

I found a way via PIL, which is:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

from PIL import Image
from numpy import array

im = Image.open('path_to_file.tif')

ncols, nrows = im.size
ima = array(im.getdata()).reshape((nrows, ncols))
plt.imshow(ima, cmap=cm.Greys_r)
```

May be that helps someone.

S