# How to read and enhance contrast of 32bit .tiff image using opencv2 in python coding?

Tags: python, opencv

As I tried to code the opencv2 to read the tiff image file, It show up

> OpenCV TIFF: TIFFRGBAImageOK: Sorry, can not handle images with 32-bit samples

I should expect that the opencv will read the file and process it with enhance contrast a bit.

here is the code:

```
import os
import cv2

input_folder = 'path'
output_folder = 'path'

# Loop through all TIFF files in the input folder
for filename in os.listdir(input_folder):
    if filename.endswith('.tiff'):
        image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(input_folder, filename), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

        alpha = 1.0035
        beta = 0
        enhanced_image = cv2.convertScaleAbs(image, alpha=alpha, beta=beta)

        output_filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '_enhanced.tif'
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(output_folder, output_filename), enhanced_image)
```

For the image tiff file, i have upload [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jnj-NX8TeZuF3kLhPO9Af4TeOgx9a5rL/view?usp=sharing) and please use ImageJ to view it.

Update (1), I have tried [How do you read a 32-bit TIFF image in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751523/how-do-you-read-a-32-bit-tiff-image-in-python) But it seem have another error which is this

> can't open/read file: check file path/integrity

Followed by

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:783: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'

Comment: Your linked file is inaccessible - maybe try sharing via Google Drive. Try placing another, simpler TIFF in the directory instead of the existing one and see if your paths/filenames are parsing correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV doesn't support reading Tiff image in float format (at least not the standard Python version).
We may use [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) for reading the image:

```
import tifffile
...
image = tifffile.imread(filename)
```

---

There are multiple ways to enhance the contrast of the image.
Two examples: "Linear stretching" and [CLAHE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_histogram_equalization).

- Linear stretching (from my [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74034178/4926757)):
  Find minimal and maximal percentile, and apply linear "stretch" such that low percentile goes to 0, and high_prc percentile goes to 255:

  ```
   def lin_stretch_img(img, low_prc, high_prc):
       lo, hi = np.percentile(img, (low_prc, high_prc))  # Example: 1% - Low percentile, 99% - High percentile

       if lo == hi:
           return np.full(img.shape, 128, np.uint8)  # Protection: return gray image if lo = hi.

       stretch_img = (img.astype(np.float32) - lo) * (255/(hi-lo))  # Linear stretch: lo goes to 0, hi to 255.
       stretch_img = stretch_img.clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)  # Clip range to [0, 255] and convert to uint8
       return stretch_img
  ```
- [OpenCV CLAHE](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/db6/classcv_1_1CLAHE.html):
  Enhancing the contrast in each block, allows much higher contrast compared to the linear stretching.
  Since CLAHE in OpenCV does not support `float32`, we have to convert the image to `uint16` type before applying CLAHE.

  ```
   image_as_uint16 = cv2.normalize(image, None, 0, 65535, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_16U) # Convert to uint16 before applying CLAHE
   clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=20, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
   cl1 = clahe.apply(image_as_uint16)  # CLAHE in OpenCV does not support float32 apply CLAHE to the uint16 image.
   cl1 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(cl1, alpha=255/65535)  # Convert from uint16 to uint8
  ```

---

Code sample:

```
import os
import cv2
import tifffile
import numpy as np

def lin_stretch_img(img, low_prc, high_prc):
    """ 
    Apply linear "stretch" - low_prc percentile goes to 0, 
    and high_prc percentile goes to 255.
    The result is clipped to [0, 255] and converted to np.uint8
    """
    lo, hi = np.percentile(img, (low_prc, high_prc))  # Example: 1% - Low percentile, 99% - High percentile

    if lo == hi:
        return np.full(img.shape, 128, np.uint8)  # Protection: return gray image if lo = hi.

    stretch_img = (img.astype(np.float32) - lo) * (255/(hi-lo))  # Linear stretch: lo goes to 0, hi to 255.
    stretch_img = stretch_img.clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)  # Clip range to [0, 255] and convert to uint8
    return stretch_img


filename = 'top_high_1493_2065_132_132_0.tiff'

#image = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
image = tifffile.imread(filename)

alpha = 1.0035
beta = 0
enhanced_image = cv2.convertScaleAbs(image, alpha=alpha, beta=beta)

# Apply "linear stretching" (lower percentile 0.1 goes to 0, and percentile 99.9 to 255).
lin_enhanced_image = lin_stretch_img(image, 0.1, 99.9)

# Normalizing frame to range [0, 65535], and get the result as type uint16. (65535 = 2**16-1)
image_as_uint16 = cv2.normalize(image, None, 0, 65535, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_16U) # Convert to uint16 before applying CLAHE
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=20, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
cl1 = clahe.apply(image_as_uint16)  # CLAHE in OpenCV does not support float32 apply CLAHE to the uint16 image.
cl1 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(cl1, alpha=255/65535)  # Convert from uint16 to uint8

output_filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '_enhanced.tif'
cv2.imwrite(output_filename, enhanced_image)

cv2.imwrite(os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '_lin_enhanced.tif', lin_enhanced_image)

cv2.imwrite(os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '_cl1_enhanced.tif', cl1)
```

---

CLAHE output for example:
[image]
The contrast is enhanced, but the input image is mainly noise...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Skimage to read, stretch the dynamic range and write your result in Python. Here I stretch the dynamic range to full dynamic range and save to both 8-bit and 32-bit results.

```
from skimage import io
from skimage import exposure
import numpy as np

# read 32-bit tiff using skimage
img = io.imread('top_high_1493_2065_132_132_0.tiff', as_gray=True)
print(img.shape)

# get input min and max values   
imin=np.amin(img)
imax=np.amax(img)
print(imin, imax)

# stretch dynamic range using skimage
result8 = exposure.rescale_intensity(img, in_range=(imin,imax), out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
result32 = exposure.rescale_intensity(img, in_range=(imin,imax), out_range='dtype').astype(np.float32)

# save results
io.imsave('top_high_1493_2065_132_132_0_stretch8.tiff', result8)
io.imsave('top_high_1493_2065_132_132_0_stretch32.tiff', result32)

# show result
io.imshow(result8) 
io.imshow(result32) 
io.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `cv2.imread(fullImagePath, flags=(cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH))`

ref

[How do you read a 32-bit TIFF image in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751523/how-do-you-read-a-32-bit-tiff-image-in-python)

Comment: Hi, it shows that "can't open/read file: check file path/integrity" and in the last line, [cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:783: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite']